# Eliminar duplicados de la ultima columna en c#

Tags: c#, array, matrices

Tengo una matriz de 3 filas por 4 columnas matriz[3,4]:
ABCD
EFGH
DKLM

y quiero eliminar los elementos que sean iguales a [i,3] (es decir los elementos de la ultima columna) en caso que sean iguales a cualquiera de los elementos que están dentro de los valores de [i,j] (j solo va hasta 2 porque no tomo la ultima columna). Por ejemplo: se elimina D ya que D está en la ultima columna (matriz[0,3]) porque se repite en matriz[2,0] y el resultado pasarlo a un mi_array sin los valores repetidos, resultado igual: mi_array={A, B, C, E, F, G, H, K, L, M}

Answer (score 0):

Si el resultado final sera un array simple de una sola dimension podrias aplanar los datos de la matriz y luego aplicar el `linq` con el `group by`

```
List<string> items = new List<string>();

for(int i = 0; i<3;i++)
    for(int j = 0; j<4;i++)
       items.Add(matriz[i,j]);

string[] mi_array = (from item in items
                      group item by item into g
                      where g.Count() == 1
                     select g.Key).ToArray();
```